# wget saving html files as .en files instead of html files

Tags: wget

I am using wget to download help.ubuntu.com so I will be able to use it offline. I downloaded the entire web page with the command

```
wget -U firefox -m -l -D help.ubuntu.com --follow-ftp -np "https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/" -e robots=off
```

Everything was fine until I tried navigating the saved pages. The index.html is fine, but when i follow a link, it breaks and just shows the html code for the next page. I think it has to do with how the files were saved because the pages are saved like example.ubuntu.help.html.en

So my question is, implying I entered the command correctly, how do I change the saved pages to end with just .html and not .en? I'm fine with having to re-download the pages, but I wonder if this normal or if I messed up with the command.

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was that I was using the brave-browser. Everything worked fine when I swapped to Firefox. If only my brain saved me some embarrassment, I wouldn't be so embarrassed lol.